# Comparing two groups - stacked bar chart with representation of each data point

Tags: data, legending, visualization, charts

I have a dataset comparing the performance of students on two exams, Exam 1 and Exam 2:
[image]

I would like to create a stacked bar chart where each bar represents the grades on Exam 1 and the stacks in each bar represent the grades on Exam 2. Here's the catch: instead of having solid bars representing the number of students, I want to have a symbol (eg, circle) represent each student. See drawing below:
[image]

So by counting the number of dots in the A column, I know how many students got an A on Exam 1. By counting the total number of green dots, I know how any students got an A on Exam 2. By counting the number of green dots in column A, I know how many students got As on Exam 1 and Exam 2.

I am, of course, open to any suggestions on how to display data of this type that conveys the same information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** Using a custom `ChartElementFunction` to represent each data point with a disk:

```
ClearAll[ceF]
ceF[nc_: 5, sz_: 5, shft_: 5][ clr_: "Pastel"] := 
  Module[{nrows, disks, bb = Charting`ChartStyleInformation["BoundingBox"][[2]], 
     ncols = Range[#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]], (#[[1, 2]] - #[[1, 1]])/(nc - 1)], 
     cols = If[Head[clr] === String, 
      ColorData[clr] /@ Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[#3[[1]]] - 1)], clr]}, 
    nrows = Range[## & @@ (shft+bb), (bb[[2]] - bb[[1]])/Quotient[bb[[2]] - bb[[1]], nc]];
    disks = Disk[#, Offset[sz]] & /@ (Reverse /@ Tuples[{nrows, ncols}][[;; #2]]); 
    Thread[{Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ Thread[{cols, #3[[1]]}], disks}]] &;
```

**Examples:**

Use the total of each data group as main data and pass its breakdown as metadata to be processed by the `ChartElementFunction` to render bars filled with appropriate number of colored disks:

```
data = {{10, 8, 2}, {12, 15, 4}, {5, 7, 7}};
bcdata = Thread[Total /@ data -> data];

Labeled[BarChart[bcdata, ChartElementFunction -> ceF[][], 
  BarSpacing -> {1, 0}, ChartLabels -> {Style[#, 16] & /@ {"A", "B", "<=C"}}, 
  Axes -> {True, False}, 
  ChartLegends -> SwatchLegend["Pastel", Style[#, 16] & /@ {"A", "B", "<=C"}, 
    LegendLayout -> "ReversedColumn", 
    LegendLabel -> Style["Exam 2 Grades", 16, "Panel"]]], 
 {Rotate[Style["Counts", 16, "Panel"], 90 Degree], 
  Style["Exam 1", 16, "Panel"]}, {Left, Bottom}]
```

[image]

Use `ChartElementFunction -> ceF[][{Red, Green, Blue}]` with appropriate changes in the legend to get

[image]

Use `ChartElementFunction -> ceF[3, 7][{Red, Green, Blue}]` to get larger disks arranged in three columns:

[image]

etc..

**Original answer:**

```
data = {{10, 8, 2}, {12, 15, 4}, {5, 7, 7}};
```

Using a standard `BarChart` you can do

```
Labeled[BarChart[data, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
   ChartLabels -> {Style[#, 16] & /@ {"A", "B", "<=C"}, None},
   ChartLegends -> SwatchLegend[Style[#, 16] & /@ {"A", "B", "<=C"}, 
     LegendLayout -> "ReversedColumn", 
     LegendLabel -> Style["Exam 2 \nGrades", 16, "Panel"]]], 
 {Rotate[Style["Count", 16, "Panel"], 90 Degree], Style["Exam 1", 16, "Panel"]}, 
 {Left, Bottom}]
```

[image]

Use `labeleddata`

```
labeleddata = Thread[Labeled[#, StringJoin @@@ Thread[{{"A : ", "B : ", "<=C : "}, 
  ToString /@ #}], Center]] & /@ data;
```

as the first argument of `BarChart` above to get

[image]